# Object and Class comparator

Tags: java, class, comparison, equals

I want to compare two Objects:

```
isEqual(Object left, Object right);
```

However, when I pass a class `java.lang.Integer` and a `class java.lang.String`, they both get treated as a Class type and I can't compare them with accuracy. Is there any other way to do this?

```
public boolean isEqual(Object left, Object right) {

    Class<?> leftClass = left.getClass(); 
    Class<?> rightClass = right.getClass();

    // if classes are different return false
    if (!leftClass.equals(rightClass)) { //leftClass and rightClass both have the value class java.lang.Class
        if (!(leftClass.isAssignableFrom(rightClass) || rightClass.isAssignableFrom(leftClass))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
return true
}
```

Comment: I guess a better option would be using `public boolean sameClass(Object left, Object right, Class<?> clazz)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `left` and `right` can be objects as well as classes, then you'd have to check that first:

```
Class<?> leftClass;
if( left instanceof Class) {
  leftClass = (Class)left;
}
else {
  leftClass = left.getClass();
}

//or in one line:
Class<?> leftClass = left instanceof Class ? (Class)left : left.getClass();

//do the same for right
```

If `left` and `right` can *only* be classes, then I'd change the parameter types to `Class<?> left` etc.

Comment: they can be any king of object. thanks for your help. it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test whether a String and an Integer are equal, that implies to me you want to test `String` equality. So, I would do that instead -

```
public boolean isEqual(Object left, Object right) {
  if (left == null) return right == null;
  else if (right == null) return false;
  return left.toString().equals(right.toString());
}
```